# Converting Pandas Dataframe to Tensorflow Dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, tensor

I am trying to convert a Pandas Dataframe to a Tensorflow Dataset. The DataFrame includes three columns:

1. Target - Binary [1/0]
2. Feature1 - List of Integers.
3. Feature2 - List of Integers.

Feature1 and Feature2 are lists of indices based on Tensorflow's TokenTextEncoder. First row example below:

Target    Feature1    Feature2
  1       [1,2,3,5]   [6,7,9,10]

The goal is to create a binary classification based on both feature sets.

I have tried converting the lists to numpy arrays, but I still get the same error.

```py
target = df.pop('Target')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, target.values))
```

TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got [399, 309, 34, 383, 281]

Comment: Perhaps it is a version error. This works for me on TF 2.0.

Comment: @cs95 `code Unfortunately, it is still producing the error. I incorporated the following:         q=pd.DataFrame(df['Feature1'].values.tolist()).add_prefix('wls_')
r=pd.DataFrame(df['Feature2'].values.tolist()).add_prefix('ship_')
s=pd.DataFrame(df['Target'])

zz=pd.merge(pd.merge(q,r,left_index=True,right_index=True),s,left_index=True,right_index=True)                                                                                               target = zz.pop('Target')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((zz.values, target.values))`